# Group by error in SQL

Tags: sql

Can someone look at my select statement and offer some help? I have a field that has a whole number value that I need to convert to a decimal and depending on if that value is > 0 or not, then do some more math to ultimately get the discounted cost after the discount percent is taken off. The problem is it wants to put the discount field into my group by clause which I do not want since it then will group the discounted ones seperate from the not discounted ones. Hopefully this makes sense. Here is the statement.

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN ITEMS.DISCOUNT > 0 THEN 
                (
                     SUM(ITEMS.IT_UNLIST * QUANTS) 
                     - SUM(ITEMS.IT_UNLIST * QUANTS) 
                     * CAST((ITEMS.DISCOUNT/100) as DECIMAL(8,2))
                 )
            ELSE 
                SUM(ITEMS.IT_UNLIST * QUANTS) 
        END AS Sales
        , MONTH(ITEMS.IT_SDATE) AS Mnth
        , CUST.STATE
```

I group by Mnth, then by State and thats all I want to group by. I am pretty new to sql so any advice would be appreciated. Any thoughts?

Comment: where is rest of the query ??

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you need to have all fields in a grouped query that you aren't grouped on wrapped in an aggregate function.

So, assuming that all of your fields are contained and joined:

```
SELECT 
    CUST.STATE,
    MONTH(Items.IT_SDATE) as Mnth,  
    SUM(
        ITEMS.IT_UNLIST * QUANTS
        - ( CAST((ITEMS.DISCOUNT/100) as DECIMAL(8,2)) * ITEMS.IT_UNLIST * QUANTS)
        )
    ) as Sales
FROM Cust, Items
GROUP BY
    CUST.STATE,
    MONTH(Items.IT_SDATE)
```

Note that I removed your superfluous CASE statement, and wrapped the entire expression in a single SUM().  You could also calculate a SUM() of all discounts and then subtract it, but if you really want that you would need to wrap the `ITEMS.DISCOUNT` in its own SUM.

Comment: Oh, and don't do a cross join ('FROM Cust, Items') if you can at all avoid it.  Having a proper INNER JOIN will do far more to speed your query than a CASE ever could.

Answer (score 0):

Since only `SELECT` clause provided in this question, I can only be partially sure that this will work as expected. To group only by `Mnth` and `State`, you need to wrap whole select statement for `Sales` column inside aggregate function (I believe it is `SUM` in this case) :

```
SELECT SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN ITEMS.DISCOUNT > 0 THEN 
                (
                     ITEMS.IT_UNLIST * QUANTS
                     - ITEMS.IT_UNLIST * QUANTS
                     * CAST((ITEMS.DISCOUNT/100) as DECIMAL(8,2))
                 )
            ELSE 
                ITEMS.IT_UNLIST * QUANTS
        END
        ) AS Sales
        , MONTH(ITEMS.IT_SDATE) AS Mnth
        , CUST.STATE
FROM ........
GROUP BY MONTH(ITEMS.IT_SDATE), CUST.STATE
```

Note that if `ITEMS.DISCOUNT` is never NULL (it is 0 when there is no discount), you don't need the `ELSE` part, and therefore don't need `CASE WHEN` statement as also pointed by @DougM.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(ITEMS.IT_UNLIST * QUANTS 
           * (1 - CASE WHEN ITEMS.DISCOUNT > 0
                       THEN CAST(ITEMS.DISCOUNT AS DECIMAL(8,2)) / 100
                       ELSE 0 
                  END)) AS Sales
    , MONTH(ITEMS.IT_SDATE) AS Mnth
    , CUST.STATE
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY MONTH(ITEMS.IT_SDATE), CUST.STATE
```